# Country wise wordpress website on same domain

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am building a wordpress website where the user has to first select country.

Different countries has different service ex say service A and Service B. For some countries only one kind is service is present.

So now as soon as we open home page say abc.com

-->The user should select country
abc.com/USA

-->Once he selects country he should be able to select language if there are 
multiple languages.

-->Once he selects language the user can choose service A or service B.
abc.com/USA/ServiceA

-->Once he selects Service, the pages corresponding to particular services come up. (About Service, contact about the service etc)
In short the Service A or Service B is actual website with all pages. But before that user has to select country,language,service.

Is there any premium plugin that helps creating this kind of website?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is multiple plugins for multi language. WPML is best but it is paid and support is good. You can choose transposh wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 2):

any ideas:

1) Create Multilingual WP http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-easily-create-a-multilingual-wordpress-site/

2) Create a folder in each country WP facility or a subdomain abc.com/USA or usa.abc.com , you could install a wordpress multisite http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/wordpress-wordpress-mu-and-wordpress-multisite/

3) Create Template Page on WP for selecting Country

4) Create Template Page on WP for selecting language ( Setup Multilingual WP)

5) Finally create template Page for selecting services

I would think that this can be a good way, I have no information about a plugin to do something as specific

regards